# Google Sheet Script - Set cell value based on same row extracted information

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a fully automatized Google Script option which will monitor all cells of dynamic input data (IMPORTDATA, .csv file).

Example: In column A cell content (input) is "White House, USA". Script should set column B(output) cell value in same row of column B to be "USA". But there can be multiple input and output options.

| **Col A** | **Col B** |
| --- | --- |
| White House, USA | USA |
| Будинок Уряду, Ukraine | UKRAINE |

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try in B1

```
=arrayformula(iferror(regexextract(A1:A,", (.*)")))
```

[regexextract](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: Nice one, and it's working! But I guess this depends on the input data would nede to be kind of static, always the second word after the comma. That would work in the example, but my values can differ in many variations.

The input could also be "Country (United States), White House" and I still need the script to interpret it as "USA".

I think it must be a script, probably multiple scripts, because the predefined input searches could be 100 to 200 variations, while the output values will be much less and easy filterable options.

Comment: You obviously have to build a corresponding table between the extensive descriptions and the abbreviations

Comment: Yes, I have been hinted about that before and that is no problem to do that. So, let's say I have that corresponding table ready. Then what would be the next step?

Comment: Can you share a simple spreadsheet with a few sentences and a draft of the table. This will come in handy as I'm a little busy.

Comment: Sample spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SsGIdNXN9cMmHsySX5lmb9H1GT558Cpd_vWNbqsPGc8/edit#gid=1062910779

Comment: Done in columns E, F and G

Comment: Im impressed, done solely with formula. But wouldn't that solution be vulnerable to inconsistency of input data? example: "1 - 4" instead of "1", where output should be "1-4"?

Comment: I mean: example: "1 to 4" instead of "1-4", where output should still be "1-4"?

Comment: may be add some examples, i will take them into account. for what you are saying, you can replace (\d) by ([0-8\- ]+)

Comment: What is the output should be text, example "Superuser", 
ref to Rule 10 in sheet

Comment: `=iferror(regexextract($A10,".*\(([0-9 \-]+) users"),iferror(regexextract($A10,".*User (\d+)"),1))`

Comment: Unfortunately the solution will not be flexible enough. Ex. check cell F11. (Mod. 28)